# oniteminvoked not firing WinJS Listview

Tags: listview, winjs, listviewitem

I have been looking for some answers about this issue  on my code and I can't fine different answers because as far as I've seen there are not many answers to this.

I Have a ListView that is being filled with with some server content (note app) I seem able to change selectionMode, tapBehavior and some different properties of the ListView using the `WinJS.UI.procesAll().then(//code here);`
but the only one that is not working at all though Chrome dev tools tell me there is actually an eventhandler for oninvokeditem but once I click nothing seems to work, any breakpoints I put aren't hit at all.
here's some code:

```
var WinJSRequest = function (uri, method, data) {
    var request = {
        url: uri,
        type: method,
        contentType: "application/json",
        accepts: "application/json",
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization",
                "Basic " + btoa(username + ":" + password));
        },
        error: function (jqXHR) {
            //console.log(data);
            console.log("ajax error " + jqXHR.status);
        }
    };
    return WinJS.xhr(request).done(
        function completed(request) {
            var arr = JSON.parse(request.response);
            for (var i = 0; i < arr.tareas.length; i++) {
                tareas.push(arr.tareas[i]);
            }
            WinJS.Namespace.define("App.Notas", {
                data: new WinJS.Binding.List(tareas)
            });
            WinJS.UI.processAll().then( function() {
                listaTareas = WinJS.Utilities.query('#listaTareas');
                listaTareas = listaTareas[0].winControl;
                listaTareas.oniteminvoked = function (ev) {
                    console.log('index: ' + ev.detail.itemIndex);
                };
            });
        },
        function error(request) {
            alert(request);
        },
        function progress(request) {
            //alert(request);
            console.log('In Progress');
        });
};
```

and Here's some HTML

```
    <!-- Template para el Listview -->
    <div id="listviewTemplate">
        <div class="listViewNotasTemplate" data-win-control="WinJS.Binding.Template">
            <div class="listviewItemNota">
                <h1 class="win-h1" data-win-bind="textContent: titulo"></h1>
                <h3 class="win-h3" data-win-bind="textContent: descripcion"></h3>
                <h5 class="win-h5" data-win-bind="textContent: hecho"></h5>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Codigo del ListView -->
    <div id="listaTareas" class="listView win-selectionstylefilled" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ListView" data-win-options="{
                itemDataSource: App.Notas.data.dataSource,
                itemTemplate: select('.listViewNotasTemplate'),
                selectionMode: 'multi',
                tapBehavior:'toggleSelect',
                layout: { type: WinJS.UI.ListLayout }
            }"></div>
    <!-- Termino el ListView -->
    <script src="node_modules/winjs/js/base.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/winjs/js/ui.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/index.js"></script>
```

there's nothing else pretty much that's all the body.
I have tried to use `listaTareas.addEventListener('oniteminvoked', handler, false);`,
I tried to declare it on the HTML Control and yet nothing, perhaps is just something I'm not looking help anyone?

Thanks in advance :)

EDIT: for the record as I was looking at the console i found that the oniteminvoked: (...)
found this on
arguments: TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them
    at Function.remoteFunction (:3:14)
    at Object.InjectedScript.callFunctionOn (:750:66)

Comment: for the record, I'm Using WinJS 4.0.0 and jQuery

Answer (score 0):

There is an error on your event name:

listaTareas.addEventListener('iteminvoked', handler, false)

without 'on' ;)

Comment: hey! thanks for the response but i'm afraid i tested that way too, didn't mention it my bad. but still doesn't work that way :(

Comment: if i use it like this `listaTareas.addEventListener('click', handler, false);` it actually executes the handler but in all the list, even in the blank spaces of the list.